# Outlook Redemption and safeMail hangs on exit

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have a problem where my app is hanging on exit when I try to use saafeMail. If I run the code in the debugger the program exists normally, but when I run outside the debugger it hangs at exit.

```
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();  
session.Logon(null, null, false, null, null, null);  
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();  
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");  
Outlook.MailItem newMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as  Outlook.MailItem;  

SafeMailItem safeMail = new SafeMailItem();

safeMail.Item = newMail;  
safeMail.Recipients.Add("jon@domain.no");  
safeMail.Recipients.ResolveAll();  
newMail.Subject = "Subject";  
safeMail.Body = "TextBody";  
safeMail.Send();  

Thread.Sleep(1000); // tried to add this to allow any pending COM operations to finish

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(safeMail);  
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newMail);  
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookNamespace);  
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookApp);  
session.Logoff();  
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session);
```

I guess there is a problem releasing COM objects? Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still leaking a COM object reference since you are using multiple dot notation. Replace the following lines

```cs
safeMail.Recipients.Add("jon@domain.no");  
safeMail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
```

with

```cs
var recipients = safeMail.Recipients;
var recip = recipients.Add("jon@domain.no");  
recip.Resolve();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipients);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recip);
```

You can also create a recipient in a resolved state using

```cs
var recipients = safeMail.Recipients;
var recip = recipients.AddEx("jon", "jon@domain.no", "SMTP", OlMailRecipientType.olTo);  
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipients);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recip);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the program still hang on exit. (tried both versions of creating recipient).
Can you see any other potential problems?

Comment: The rest of your code looks fine, even though `RDOSession` object does not do anything. Have you tried `GC.Collect()` at the very end?

Comment: GC.Collect() did not change anything, but removed RDOSession and then it worked like a charm! The RDOSession was something left by mistake from before converting to safeMail. Thank you!